# How to show userControl on all screen?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have user control that i wrote. 
this user control is appear on some Window ( host ) and the window size is dynamic. 
I want to make the user control size to be also dynamic - and if the window host size is change ( grow / shrink ) then the user control also will change.

I try a lot of thinks - but the user control size is not changing ( also try to mark the user control as 'fill' and its not working. )

How to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Need more details. This window is WPF window or u r trying to host your control in Winforms? Make sure you don't have any Height/width set in your user control. Will be great if you can post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the controls on the user control grow and shrink too, and to do this use the [DockPanel](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DockPanel.html) and [GridPanel](http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) (WPF) or the [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) or [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) properties (WinForms). Then when the control itself is resized, the controls will resize automatically also